# list index out of bound in Python

Tags: python

```
target_sum = int(input())
arr_list = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

for i in range(len(arr_list)):
    sum=0
    sum += arr_list[i] + arr_list[i+1]
    print(sum)
```

> 11 22 33 44 55
>
> 33 55 77 99
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "abc.py", line 10, in
>   
>       `sum += arr_list[i] + arr_list[i+1]` IndexError: list index out of range Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: `for i in range(len(arr_list) - 1)`. It will help with error, but it won't fix logic.

Comment: what is the sample input & expected output?

Comment: sample input 1 2 3 4
sample output 3 5 7

Comment: @OlvinRoght its works good

Comment: The last element of for will be out of range because of i+1

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the last iteration you try to access an element that does not exist.

try with this:

```
target_sum = input()
arr_list = [int(x) for x in target_sum.split(" ")]

for i in range(len(arr_list)-1):
    sum = 0
    sum = arr_list[i] + arr_list[i+1]
    print(sum)
```

If you want you can make a condition to check if the length of the list is bigger than 1:

```
target_sum = input()
arr_list = [int(x) for x in target_sum.split(" ")]

if len(arr_list) < 2:
    print("not enougth values")
    exit(0)

for i in range(len(arr_list)-1):
    sum = 0
    sum = arr_list[i] + arr_list[i+1]
    print(sum)
```

if you want to print the result on a single line, you can add the end parameter to the print function like this:

```
for i in range(len(arr_list)-1):
    sum = 0
    sum = arr_list[i] + arr_list[i+1]
    print(sum, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical *one-off-error*.
Functional programming (FP) reduces such occurrence a lot, and makes checks like `len(lst)` superfluous.

Here, you want to sum up two neighboring elements of the given list.

A typical idiom for this in pythonic FP is:

```
lst = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
[ x + y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) ]

# input: 11 22 33 44 55
# output: [33, 55, 77, 99]
```

The trick here is that with `lst[1:]` you generate `lst` shifted by 1. However, this is by 1 shorter than `lst`.
The `zip()` pairs each element of `lst` with the corresponding in `lst[1:]`. The last element of `lst` has no corresponding partner. But zip ignores such pairings.

```
lst = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]

zip(lst, lst[1:]) # generates from:

# lst       lst[1:]
#
# 11         22
# 22         33
# 33         44
# 44         55
# 55

# "zipping" to ->
[(11, 22),
 (22, 33),
 (33, 44),
 (44, 55)]
# (55, None) -> eliminated, zip stops where the shorter list
# stops
# however, zip() is in python also lazy (similar to map())
# its output is a generator.
# so when you want to inspect it, you have to do list(zip(...))
# to enforce its full execution, as with all generators...
#


# for x, y in [(11, 22), (22, 33), (33, 44), (44, 55)]
# loads each of the pair components on x and y
# and the expression at the beginning of the list-expression
# x + y  collects the sum of those.
```

Actually in functional terms it is a case for `map()`.
However, in python, you have to enforce with `list()`
the generator-like `map()`.

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, lst, lst[1:])) 
# map processes the two lists in parallel similar to zip
# but gives the corresponding elements of each list
# directly to the arguments in the lambda expression/function:
# here to x and y.

11 22 33 44 55
## [33, 55, 77, 99]
```

So, by applying functional programming, you will be less exposed to such kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `arr_list[i+1]`, when you reach the last index `i`, it will look for `i+1` which doesn't exist, thus the error.

There are a couple of workarounds:

1) decrease the range `range(len(arr_list) -1)`

2) use try/except:

```
for i in range(len(arr_list)):
    try:
        sum=0
        sum += arr_list[i] + arr_list[i+1]
        print(sum)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

3) You can rethink your strategy. I, for example, would do something like this:

```
a = arr_list[:-1]
b = arr_list[1:]

for x,y in zip(a,b):
    print(x+y)
```

Also, mind that `sum()` is a Python function, it would be better to use another variable name.

Comment: you don't have to shorten by `arr_list[:-1]`. `zip()` stops with the shortest list anyway (see my answer).

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Yes, you are right, it was to highlight the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was applying `int()` casting on `input()`, when your inputs were space separated values.

You can also perform the sum using a single-line of list-comprehension.

```py
arr_list = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
target_sum = [a+b for a, b in zip(arr_list[0:-1], arr_list[1:])]
```

### Example

```py
target_sum = input() # 11 22 33 44 55
arr_list = [int(x) for x in target_sum.split()]
[a+b for a, b in zip(arr_list[0:-1], arr_list[1:])]
## Output
# [33, 55, 77, 99]
```

Comment: @bhavesh-sadhu Please try this out and let me know if you have questions.